# Delete the document in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to delete the document in elasticserach by timestamp and one of the custom field "cu_hostname".
I want to remove all the documents which are in the specific time stamp which have the value "cu_hostname=abc"

I have written a query for timestamp as below:

```
POST filebeat-perf-1/_delete_by_query
{
"query":{
"range": {
"@timestamp": {
"gte": "1510511400000",
"lte": "1510597799000"
}
}
}
}
```

and deleting the custom field:

```
  curl -XPOST '10.193.104.42:9200/filebeat-perf-1/_delete_by_query?conflicts=proceed&pretty' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
    {
    "query": {
    "wildcard": {
    "cu_hostname": "abc"
    }
    }
    }
```

How to combine both this query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to combine both with a `bool/filter` query:

```
POST filebeat-perf-1/_delete_by_query
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": "1510511400000",
              "lte": "1510597799000"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "wildcard": {
            "cu_hostname": "abc"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```